# How to read an Excel sheet with multiple sheets, and edit only a single sheet

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I have a program which picks up values from an XML sheet and writes them into an excel sheet, using TestWriter.

```
FileStream ostrm;
                StreamWriter strm;
                TextWriter txtWrt = Console.Out;
                ostrm = new FileStream(path + "\\Output.xls", FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write);
```

Now the output file, Output.xls has multiple tabs, but I only have to truncate and write into the first sheet, leaving the other tabs untouched. I was using the below code, but it deleted all other tabs and edited the first tab.

```
public Excel.Application app = null;
    public Excel.Workbook workBook = null;
    public Excel.Worksheet workSheet = null;
    app = new Excel.Application();
            workBook = app.Workbooks.Add();
            workSheet = (Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            workBook.SaveAs(path+ "\\Output.xls");
            workBook.Close();
            app.Quit();
```

I need to find a way by which this can be avoided.

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0):

MSDN states that FileMode.Truncate "Specifies that the operating system should open an existing file. When the file is opened, it should be truncated so that its size is zero bytes." You can try changing to FileMode.OpenOrCreate instead, and then clear the tab before writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the truncate command in the way you describe. Its intended for text files.
For starters why are you usng FileStream?

You should be using the XLSX open xml format Excel file type, and using the Open XML SDK.
here is one article that explains how
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670141/Read-and-Write-Microsoft-Excel-with-Open-XML-SDK

Whilst XLS format can accept xml data it is not designed to interoperate as efficiently as a XLSX format file.
While you can get away with using filestream for small operations it is limited and you have already run into those limitations.